# It's funny that you should say that. Why "say" not "said"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, archaicisms, should

There's an exercise in Murphy's Grammar in use unit 34.

"It's funny that you ***should say*** that. I was going to say the same thing."

Why not use past tense "said" but "say" here?

Another should question.
The book says use "I should" to give somebody advice.

such as:

"It's very cold this morning. I should wear a coat when you go out."
Feels a little weird.

Is this kind of grammar still used commonly today?

Comment: Looks like Murphy needs to work on his grammar.  :P  "I should" for advice sounds like pretentious BS, and doesn't make much sense syntactically.  (Unless the person going out takes the one and only space heater with him.)

Comment: @cHao It is actually perfectly normal use, at least it is something I would say (but then I am 69 years old). The full version is 'I should wear a coat...if I were you'. But the last four words are elided.

Comment: 'It's funny that you should said that' was and still is ungrammatical, and I've never heard one example of that sort of error in my life. Auxiliaries, including the modal _should_, invariably trigger the infinitive form of the verb chosen to follow them. If you're asking why "It's funny that you said that" isn't used here, this version is acceptable, but doesn't have the same connotation of surprise that the modal construction does.

Comment: The noun is *advice*. *Advise* is a verb. You cannot give advise. And we write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. "Forgetting" how to use modals is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic. So rather than striking it through, you might wish to delete it, especially for as long as there are no answers. And as a general rule, Stack Exchange works best when you limit your questions to one question per question. Thank you.

Comment: @Reg Wish me say that. I've swiped and stashed it, of course. Does it appear in the 'Guidelines'?

Comment: You don't need to delete this question. If you have a different question to ask, ask it as a different question instead of editing this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "It's funny that you **should say** that. I was going to say the same thing."

The word *should* brings it to the present. If you remove it:

> "It's funny [that] you **said** that. I was going to say the same thing."

The verb *should* has altered the tense of the statement.

Comment: *Should* triggers the bare infinitive, not the present tense.